# Find the missing parking space number

Tags: mathematics, logical-deduction, number-sequence

Each space in this parking area is numbered. The parked car covers one of the numbers. What is the number?[image]

For reference, the parking numbers are $16,06,68,88,X,98$ where $X$ is the hidden number.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's

> L8 (87 upside-down)

Reasoning

> The parking spaces are in numerical order, right to left, but we are viewing them upside-down.

Comment: .. Was it that easy.. Took you a few seconds haha

Comment: It's one of those ones where I might see it very quickly or take an age and not figure it out.

Comment: @NoLand'sMan It's also a classic - you see it pop up every once in a while.